# Is there a symbol for a magnifying glass?

Tags: pdftex, symbols

I'm interested in including a magnifying glass (like 🔍) in a tex document which has to be compilable with **pdfLaTeX**. I looked into  [The Comprehensive Latex Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf) but I didn't find any suitable symbol. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `fontawesome` package has a command `\faSearch`, and the `bclogo` package a `\bcloupe`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are using LuaLaTeX (probably also XeTeX), there are Unicode characters for left-pointing and right-pointing magnifying glass. Of course, you need to use an Open Type font that has those characters. Won't solve your current problem, but planning for the future...