# Zoom in / Zoom out symbol

Tags: fontawesome

There are [symbols for a magnifying glass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370026/101831) in LaTeX but I want something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See for iinstance the `stackinset` command (`stackengine` package).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `tikz` machinery.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% \node[draw,line width=2pt,circle,inner sep=2pt] (A) at (0,0) {$-$};
\node[draw,line width=2pt,circle,inner sep=2pt] (A) at (0,0) {$+$};
\draw[line width=2pt] ($(A.225)+(.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth)$) -- ++(-1em,-1em);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

I use instead `fontawesome5` package of Marcel Kruger of the June 7, 2019 (the lens grip should be different from `fontawesome` with the command `\reflectbox` to obtain the very similar image of the user @Sr. Schneider.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\faSearchPluss}{\reflectbox{\faSearchPlus}}
\newcommand{\faSearchMinuss}{\reflectbox{\faSearchMinus}}
\begin{document}
\faSearchPluss, \faSearchMinuss
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Finally found it in the `fontawesome` package: `\faSearchPlus` and `\faSearchMinus`.

[image]

Comment: No no, please. I not want the green check mark. It is correct that the green tick is Marian's, the first one you gave. Just for the honesty.